# Can Cucumber be used for forms testing

Tags: html, angular, forms, testing, cucumber

I have worked on Angular testing using Protractor for end to end, but now I want to test using Cucumber and Gherkin. Since they are used for BDD and use features and scenarious I have a question: can I use Cucumber to test angular forms, for example if I click on the name filed to test if the attribute hidden is there or not, something like this? Or if a button is disabled or not? Things that you can test using Jasmine or Protractor.
I actually have my code written, don't know if it is called anymore BDD if I test the code after it is written?

Thank so much for making this clear

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Cucumber can be used to drive a browser, angular runs in the browser, so yes?

Comment: You can also integrate protractor with cucumber-js. https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/getting-started-with-protractor-and-cucumber

Comment: @DaveNewton wella ctually I am asking if It can be used to test a form that I actaully have it written, since it is made for BDD which is to write the test before coding

Comment: I'm pretty sure Cucumber won't know when you wrote your test.

Comment: So, you mean it can be done? And I can recreate the code that I have written before using Cuccumber?

Comment: The tool won't care when you write your tests. However, if you'r writing the tests *after* the code, it's not BDD (you're not driving development). Also, for Cucumber/BDD it's recommended that you describe the *behaviour* of the system, not the implementation details. Behaviour would be "user can sign up"; implementation would include "field is visible". If signup flow changes, fields may change, user being able to sign up should not ;)

Comment: I don't understand what the issue is. Cucumber doesn't know when you wrote your code or your tests. It's a test framework, not an artificial intelligence with insight into your development history. It can be used to test stuff written a decade ago. It can be used to test stuff you didn't even write. It's a test framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, don't get too hung up on "BDD". Ideally the Gherkin scenarios will be written before any development work starts to make sure the entire team - POs, design, devs, QA - are on the same page about the intended user functionality. However, even if that didn't happen, Cucumber/Gherkin can still be used to write tests after the code is created to test the functionality from the point of view of the user.

You can definitely use Cucumber to check to see that a button is disabled, or a hidden attribute is there, but that's not really the purpose of BDD tests. Those are testing user behaviors, and it's unlikely a user will ever want to visit your site to check if a hidden attribute is there. Does that make sense? The tests you're describing sound like great candidates for unit tests, and the overhead of Cucumber might be too much for that.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense. But I want to really use BDD in this case. And what I want to test is if the errors of a form really output or not, and if the save button is really disabled in the case of putting invalid data. It is part of an experiment which is firstly done in Jasmine (unitary tests) and Protractor then and now in Cucumber.

Comment: You *can* use Cucumber, but again, BDD is user behaviors so you probably shouldn't. Not being able to proceed because a button is disabled if someone has entered bad input is not a user behavior. That test belongs further down the pyramid. BDD covers what the user wants to visit your site to do. The user does not want to visit your site to trigger an error.

Comment: Not being able to proceed because a button is disabled if someone has entered bad input is not a user behavior?  I can't agree with that. I think the OP's tests are perfectly BDDs. And yes it's not easy to integrate BDD with angular forms.